# What are the Feruchemical abilities of the "God Metals" and their alloys?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn

There are two "God Metals"; Lerasium and Atium and they each have an alloy. What attributes can they store with Feruchemy?

Comment: There may now be three God metals if Harmonium exists.

Comment: But the God metals are the physical manifestations of the Shard's investiture on the planet. Similar to the Tears of Edgli flowers on Nalthis. We don't know if Sazed's investiture being a new combo Shard will form a new physical manifestation or not. Though I guess to fit the naming scheme it would be Sazedium or Sazium instead of Harmonium.

Comment: [here](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Ettmetal) has more info about Harmonium, and [WoB](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/190-rfantasy-ama-2013/#e4115) that Harmony is more than just two shards

Comment: @Antheloth It goes pretty deep into the lore, but the shards are much more fluid than that.  Not only does combining shards lead to what are essentially "new" shards; but theoretically those shards could be split up into different sets afterwords.  The shards of Adonalsium could have taken different intents, and could still be put together and split into new intents in theory.

Answer (score 5):

We do not know what [lerasium stores](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Lerasium#Feruchemical_Use), but [atium stores](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Atium#Feruchemical_Use) 'age', as seen by the [Lord Ruler](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Rashek), who [compounded](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Compounding) Feruchemical and Alomantic atium (and gold) to store vast amounts of age which enabled him to live for much longer than most humans.

They each have many alloys, but we only know of [malatium](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Malatium#Feruchemical_Use) (alloy of atium & gold) which also stores an unknown property.